# How can I re-create the spring application context for parametrized tests with dynamic properties?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-test

### Environment

- Spring Boot 3.2.x
- JDK 21
- JUnit 5.10.x

### Scenario

Imagine that the following test case exists:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = "my.flag=1")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
class MyTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Test
    void verifyOperation() {
        // verify behavior based on the value of myProperties.getFlag()
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is:

- Not specify the `"my.flag=1"` statically
- Dynamically define different values for `my.flag`, which could see a range of 1,2,3,4,5
- Repeat the test `verifyOperation` in a parameterized fashion based on each value assigned to the `flag` setting.

In other words, I would like the spring application context to be created multiple times for each value of the `flag` setting, defined dynamically. I am aware of what may be done as an alternative; I am more interested to learn if there is a pure/native/true Spring/Spring Boot way of doing this.

Can this be done?

Thank you.